# TypeScript in visual studio 2013 - Could not find symbol NgModule

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am using visual studio 2013 and i wish to develop a simple program for Angular2. The link that i followed is https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/08/angular2-using-angular2-with-typescript-for-asp-net-mvc-in-visual-studio-2015/

and i am facing out some problem which i could not understand what is the actual problem..I did follow step by step but still the problem occur. Can somebody help me ?

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Usc9j.png)

Comment: My friend you are looking solution for VS 2015 and doing it in 2013. \

Comment: Thanks Dictator, i thought is workable in any version of vs. Looks like i am wrong, after switch to vs2015 and it is workable now.